# Finding kernel of homomorphism $f:\mathbb Z \to S_8$ such that $f(1)=(1426)(257)$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $f:\mathbb Z \to S_8$ be a homomorphism such that $f(1)=(1426)(257)$ , then how to compute $\ker(f)$ and $f(20)$? I know that $f(n)=f^n(1)$ but this seems too tedious; please help

Comment: you have a product disjoint cycles, so the order of the image is just the lcm of their orders.

Comment: @Adam they're not disjoint!

Comment: Perhaps that should be the first thing OP should tackle.  Rewrite what you have as a product of disjoint cycles.

Comment: @blue well that's rather underhanded of the problem writer to make one work out the actual disjoint cycle decomposition!

Comment: I wish you would stop creating new tags with almost every question you post. The site existed for four years, and [tons of effort](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/12485/) have been put into designing the tag system. If something has not been made a tag, perhaps there is a reason for that. In this case, [group-homomorphism] is a useless tag: it's not a subfield of group theory, homomorphisms are used all over the theory.

Answer (score 5):

In $S_8$, the permutation $\sigma = (1426)(257) = (142576)$ has order $6$. Now, $$f(20) = f^{20}(1) = (142576)^{20} = (127)(456),$$ where we used the fact that $(142576)^{18} = (1)$ since $|(142576)| = 6$. For $n$ to be in $\mathrm{ker}(f)$, we need $(142576)^n = (1)$, which happens precisely when $n$ is a multiple of $6$. What can you conclude about $\mathrm{ker}(f)$?

Answer (score 2):

The kernel of any homomorphism $f$ out of $\Bbb Z$ is generated by the order of $f(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $S_8$ is a finite group, so if you look at powers of $f$ you will find that it eventually repeats.  Perhaps you can reason about how long it takes to repeat itself without explicitly drawing everything out.